# Win 3.1: Run DOS prompt in windowed mode by default?

Tags: windows-3.1

In Windows 3.1 when launching a dos program (.bat for example) it launches them in fullscreen mode (it changes resolution as well). There we can press ALT+ENTER to switch to windowed mode.

Is there a way make Win3.1 launch dos applications in windowed mode by default?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open `C:\WINDOWS\_DEFAULT.PIF` in the *PIF Editor* (PIFEDIT). Under "Display Usage", select "Windowed" and save the PIF file.

[image]

(Be sure to read the information in <kbd>F1</kbd> regarding windowed mode limitations.)

Comment: Great! Thank you. But for some reason a .bat file that started by another program opens minimized. I've tried all the settings in pif editor, nothing helped. Perhaps the program itself set some parameters that hide window? Any work around of that?

Comment: That's possible. Or perhaps it has its own .pif file, instead of the default one?

Comment: I don't think it has. Basically the program creates a temp.bat file and executing it.

Comment: Another issue I've noticed, is if .bat file is still running and I click on any other windows, the execution of .bat halted until I focus on it. This really makes it unusable :(

Comment: You'll need to enable the "Execution: Background" option for that.